# How to change the UI language in the Flash player Global Security Settings panel

Tags: security, flash-player

I am a software developer and I want to make screenshots of specific settings in the [Global Security Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) of the Flash player in Firefox.

I have a German locale Windows installation (unfortunately can not change) but Firefox itself is English. However, the panel shows it's UI in German, while the surrounding web page is English.

**How can I change the UI language of the panel to English too?**

Comment: Try setting up a system level environment variable name `LANG` set to a value of `en-US`.

Comment: Thanks @martineau, but this did not help